# Control auto-update of Passes from .pkpass

Tags: passbook

I have created some **Generic passes** which can easily be deliver to user. After installing it on Passbook it sending request for update in every 10-25 seconds (if auto-update is on), which is producing additional load on Server.

Can I increase auto-update Time Interval for passes which i am delivering OR just disable auto-update for passes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the many ways that passes can be distributed (email, web, app, mms, etc.), it is possible for passes to be stale, for example a Pass that is embedded in an App bundle may not always reflect the latest content.

To accommodate this, for all passes that contain a `webServiceURL` and `authenticationToken` will issue a call to the `Getting the Serial Numbers for Passes Associated with a Device` method of the [Passbook Webservice](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011988).  If your pass has not changed, then you should return no serial numbers to this call.  If you web service also receives a call to the `Getting the Latest Version of a Pass`, but the pass has not changed, you should issue a `304` response.

While both cases above need to be serviced by your web server, the load should not be significant if the pass has not changed, because there is no need to compile a new .pkpass bundle.

If your passes will never change, then you can omit the `webServiceURL` and `authenticationToken` keys altogether to prevent the pass from registering, but bear in mind that this will also prevent you from pushing updates to the pass.